# How to get country code and Country name using IP in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am working on an application which is based on react.js. One of the requirements in the app is to detect the location(Country) from where it is opened and then pre-fill the phone number field on a form with the flag of this country.

I am thinking that it would be done more efficiently by first detecting the IP address and then finding out the country name using this IP address. For that purpose, I have tried many libraries e.g. "iplocation", "geoip-country-lite", "ip" etc but these are not compatible with my application. Can any please suggest me other library using which I can get the country name?

Or there is any other effective solution instead of detecting the IP address e.g. getting some info from the browser which can get me the country name? Please guide.

Comment: Bro, I need the same solution for the same problem.

Answer (score 54):

You can do this without using jQuery.

Install & import axios from npm

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

Initialize your component state with country name & country code

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        countryName: '',
        countryCode: ''
    }
}
```

Add this function to your component

```
getGeoInfo = () => {
    axios.get('https://ipapi.co/json/').then((response) => {
        let data = response.data;
        this.setState({
            countryName: data.country_name,
            countryCode: data.country_calling_code
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

And call this.getGeoInfo() to set country name & country code to your state. I called that from *componentDidMount()*

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.getGeoInfo();
}
```

And you can read the state to get country name & country code

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Country Name: {this.state.countryName}</p>
            <p>Country Code: {this.state.countryCode}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What about "law perspective"? Do we need to ask user if we can get his location?

Answer (score 8):

With React hooks, this can be done like below:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

 useEffect(() => {
   fetch('https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/')
   .then( res => res.json())
   .then(response => {
    console.log("Country is : ", response);
  })
  .catch((data, status) => {
    console.log('Request failed:', data);
  });
},[])
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use an external API to get location details from the client IP address.

I've redone this to use http://api.hostip.info, which is free to use, and I'm using Fetch rather than jQuery to pull the data.

```js
function getElementText(response, elementName) {
    return response.getElementsByTagName(elementName)[0].innerHTML;
}

function getIpAddress() {

    fetch('http://api.hostip.info').then(response => {
         return response.text();
    }).then(xml => { 
        return (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
    }).then(xmlDoc => {
         countryName = getElementText(xmlDoc , "countryName");
         countryCode = getElementText(xmlDoc , "countryAbbrev");
         $("#output").html("Country name: " + countryName + "<br>" + "Country code: " + countryCode);
    });
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;line-height:30px;">

<button onclick="getIpAddress()">Click me to get IP AddressInfo </button>
  
  <div id="output">Location:</div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: These are paid services. I have already come across many of them. I don't want to use such services. Is there any other way around?

Comment: Well, the HTML5 Geolocation service can also be used, however the user will have to grant approval to give their location. If you can find a completely free IP lookup service the API approach will still work! Also, ipapi.co will allow a certain number of requests for free (I think it's 30000 a month), if you don't need a huge amount, it will work very well.

Comment: Also, maybe have a look at http://www.hostip.info/use.html, it looks like they are a free service.

Comment: They are fetching the wrong data @TerryLennox